# Teletext Subtitles on Romanian Television

Tags: hotels, romania, languages, accessibility

There is a teletext feature on the televisions in the hotel rooms. In England there was a way to get subtitles to appear by going to the teletext interface and entering 888. As far as I know this is no longer available.

In Romania, is there a special code you can enter into the teletext interface to enable subtitles? I've tried 888 but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: How you enable such features will obviously depend on the model of the TV/cable box, and probably has very little to do with Romania, or any other specific location, unless some specific government has laws dictating such a feature, which seems unlikely.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about TVs

Comment: Teletext codes are nationally standardized, so no, this is actually *not* model-dependent.

Comment: @Flimzy No, that's not how teletext works usually.

Comment: @Relaxed: It is on every TV I've ever used.

Comment: @Flimzy But that's not even relevant as an answer to my remark or the OP's question. The question is how many countries do you have experience with? Because I know several where the teletext page for subtitles is the same across many channels…

Comment: @Relaxed: It's the same across channels, because it depends on the equipment, not on the broadcast signal.

Comment: I guess the question can be read two ways: How do I turn on teletext, which is equipment-dependent, and "what is the language code for English and/or Romanian", which would not be equipment-dependent. I read it as asking the second question as a subset of the first. If the question is only about the code, it would not be equipment-dependent. In either case, however, I see the question as off-topic.

Comment: @Flimzy Well, no, it does not, it depends on the broadcast channel, which was my point all along. In Europe, you can use the same equipment on channels from different countries and you will see that the page numbers for a specific content (including subtitles) change from country to country but that channels from the same country tend to stick to the same page numbers, simply by convention.

Comment: @Flimzy It's still unclear to me exactly why you think the question is off-topic but all your comments suggest you are completely unfamiliar with [Teletext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext). That's fine but don't make assumptions, please.

Comment: @Relaxed: It's off-topic because it's not about traveling.

Comment: @Flimzy This question was inspired by a real problem that I faced when I recently went to Romania for a holiday. The tour page mentions that such things are on topic. It's as much on topic as other questions on the site that are not directly about getting on a bus, train, aeroplane or driving. I think that this question is very similar to [Making calls from Romania](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/making-calls-from-romania) which according to the views of those that closed this question should also be closed because it's about telephones.

Comment: I'm going to reopen this question, because it is a real problem you can face during traveling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad news.  While 888 will get you the teletext subtitles in Greece, Belgium and other countries, and Austria is 777, for example, Romania is one of the few EU members to have NONE for Teletext subtitling.

Source: [State of subtitling access in EU report - European Federation of Hard of Hearing People](http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/consultations/2011/audiovisual/non-registered-organisations/european-federation-of-hard-of-hearing-people-efhoh-_en.pdf) (page 20).